# Retaining response data in multiple checkboxes (Vue.js)

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuetify.js

Iam new to vue. So iam trying to experiment requests and response through web servers. I have mutiple checkboxes as shown:

```
        <li>
          <div class="config-label">Photoshop IRB</div>
          <div class="config-value">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              class="rounded text-light mr-3 bigger-checkboxes"
              value="photoshop"
              v-model="checkedCategories"
            />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="config-label">Flashpix</div>
          <div class="config-value">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              class="rounded text-light mr-3 bigger-checkboxes"
              value="flashpix"
              v-model="checkedCategories"
            />
          </div>
        </li>
```

Multiple checkboxes this way. The script is:

```
export default{
    data(){
        return {
            checkedCategories : []
        };
    },
    created() {
        this.getExtractionConfig().then((data) => {
        this.checkedCategories = data;
    });
  },
```

Now how do i retain the values of the checkboxes from the response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohkay, after debugging i found the solution for the silly lapse on my side. I had to select the key in data. So it was :

```
    created() {
        this.getExtractionConfig().then((data) => {
        this.checkedCategories = data.selected_categories;
    });
```